# Llenar ListItem o Array desde Listview en VB6

Tags: vb6

Tengo un Listview del cual selecciono algunas filas y quiero que el valor de una columna en especifico (de las filas seleccionadas) se guarde en un arreglo o listitem pero no logro hacerlo.
Aquí dejo mi código

Asi lleno el ListView desde la base de datos

```html
Public Sub LlenaLista()
On Error GoTo eError
Dim Item As ListItem
Dim idVales As ListItem

  With LstVales
        .ListItems.Clear
        .ColumnHeaders.Add , , "ID", 1500
        .ColumnHeaders.Add , , "FECHA", 1600
        .ColumnHeaders.Add , , "REFERENCIA", 1500
        .ColumnHeaders.Add , , "IMPORTE", 1500
        
        PcSql = "Select Id, Fecha, Referencia, Importe from MyTable Where Estatus='V' Order by Id"
        ExecCmd
        Set RsGral = CmdGral.Execute
        While Not RsGral.EOF
            Set Item = .ListItems.Add(text:=Trim(RsGral!Id))
            Item.ListSubItems.Add text:=RsGral!Fecha
            Item.ListSubItems.Add text:=RsGral!Referencia
            Item.ListSubItems.Add text:=Format(RsGral!Importe, "###,###,###,##0.00")
            RsGral.MoveNext
        Wend
    End With
 
eError:
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then DespliegaErrores Cnn
End Sub
```

```html
Private Sub cmdAceptar_Click()
On Error GoTo eError   
    Dim I As Integer
    Dim Item As ListItem
    Dim TotalImporte As Double
    
    With LstVales
        For I = 1 To .ListItems.count
            If .ListItems(I).checked Then       
                'aqui voy sumando los valores de la columna importe de las filas seleccionadas
                TotalImporte = Item.SubItems(3) + TotalImporte
                'ahora necesito llenar una lista o array para guardar los Id de las filas seleccionadas
                
            End If
        Next I
    End With
     
    'y envio la info a otro form, tambien debo enviar los id de las filas seleccionadas
    If Frm2.VerInfo(TotalImporte) Then
    Unload Me
    End If
eError:
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then Exit Sub
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Private Sub cmdAceptar_Click()
On Error GoTo eError   
    Dim I As Integer
    Dim Item As ListItem
    Dim TotalImporte As Double

    rem Estas variables tienen el conteo de los items que serán añadidos.
    Dim SelectedItems() As Integer
    Dim SelectedItemsCount As Integer
    
    With LstVales
        For I = 1 To .ListItems.count
            If .ListItems(I).checked Then       
                'aqui voy sumando los valores de la columna importe de las filas seleccionadas
                TotalImporte = Item.SubItems(3) + TotalImporte
                'ahora necesito llenar una lista o array para guardar los Id de las filas seleccionadas
                 SelectedItemsCount = SelectedItemsCount + 1
                 'NO USES EL REDIM, en este caso son pocos registros pero no es práctica.
                 Redim SelectedItems(SelectedItemsCount)
                 rem SelectedItems(SelectedItemsCount) = I 'Aquí va la asignación de la referencia.
            End If
        Next I
    End With
     
    'y envio la info a otro form, tambien debo enviar los id de las filas seleccionadas
    If Frm2.VerInfo(TotalImporte) Then
    Unload Me
    End If
eError:
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then Exit Sub
End Sub
```